# Ubuntu stopped booting after apt upgrade - Bluetooth hci0, command timeout Failed to send firmware data

Tags: boot, bluetooth, dell

Dell Latitude 7400
Ubuntu 20.04.2 (with dual-boot)

After an `apt upgrade`, my laptop froze.
Then I manually stopped it and rebooted it.

Now when I boot I find a black screen with the follow errors:

```
[   4.....] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc09 tx timeout
[  12.....] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-110)
[  12.....] Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
```

I can log in with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> but don't know what to do then ?

Comment: The accepted answer does not make any sense. Did you intend to accept your own answer?

Comment: I can tell you that after uninstalling "bluez" i could logged in.

Comment: Phrase accept your own answer. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to uninstall with:

```
sudo apt remove --purge --auto-remove bluez
```

Comment: I added the way i found as an answer

Comment: Didn't help on mint 20.2 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

For those concerned, in my case, the error when mount `/home` partition caused this error.

- check the error (optional)

```bsh
tail -n 100 /var/log/boot.log
```

- check mounted list (optional)

```bsh
df -h
```

- fix `/home` partition and then `reboot`

```bsh
fsck -t ext4 -r /home
```